# Correct way to include a BlocProvider in a Flutter stateful widge

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to include a blocprovider CounterCubit in a stateful widget.
Is this the correct way? I've created a StatelessWidget Uno with a blocprovider that has stateful widget UnoMain as a child.

```dart
class Uno extends StatelessWidget {
  const Uno({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => CounterCubit(),
      child: UnoMain(),
    );
  }
}


class UnoMain extends StatefulWidget {
  const UnoMain({ super.key });

  @override
  State<UnoMain> createState() => _UnoMainState();
}

class _UnoMainState extends State<UnoMain> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, int>(
        builder: (context, count) => Center(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            ...
          ],
        )),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's also a way to provide it in a `MultiBlocProvider` as well as up somewhere in the widgets tree.

`UnoMain` could also be a `StatelessWidget`, if there's no need to maintain the state of something within.